# How do I conditionally defer scripts based on the page name?

Tags: theme-development

I have the following code in functions.php. The first function correctly enqueues the script based on the page name. However, the second function always adds the 'defer' attribute.

```
function custom_scripts() {
    global $page;
    if ($page->page_name !== 'awkward_page') {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }

    // ...
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );


function defer_scripts( $tag, $handle ) {
    global $page;
    if ($page->page_name !== 'awkward_page') {
        return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $tag );
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_scripts', 10, 2 );
```

What is wrong with this code?

If this is the wrong way to conditionally add the 'defer' html attribute, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `$page` variable is not a `WP_Post` object. It is just the post ID. So to get the page title, you need to get the `WP_Post` object first from the post ID.

The reason that defer is always getting added is two-fold. First, `$page` is an integer, so `$page->page_name` will evaluate as `null` and `null` is not identically equal to 'awkward_page'. It will also throw an error or warning. Also, `page_name` is not a valid property of a WP_Post object. The correct property is `post_name` - even on pages.

```
function defer_scripts( $tag, $handle ) {

    //* Get the post object
    $page = get_post( get_the_ID() );

    //* Defer on some condition
    if( 'awkward_page' !== $page->post_name ) {
      $tag = str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $tag );
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_scripts', 10, 2 );
```